# ng-click not gettring triggered in accordian mode for ui-bootstarp-tpls.js when browser is adjusted

Tags: angularjs

ng-click works in normal tabs mode, but wont in accordian mode

**HTML as below:**

```
<li ng-click="SetDestVisitedState()" ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" heading="Destinations Visited" ui-sref="cpPersonaldetails.details.dstvst"  href="#/cppd/dt/dstvst" style="">
        <a href="" ng-click="select()" >Destinations Visited</a>
    </li>
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
'use strict'
angular
.module('moduleName')
.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', '$state',
    function ($scope, $state) {

        $scope.SetDestVisitedState = function () {
            alert('Dest');
        }

    }]);
```

In normal mode, the **SetDestVisitedState ** works fine, but in accordian mode it wont.

Please note i am using **ui-bootstrap-tpls.js** to make it to normal to accordian when browser is adjusted.

Find the jsFiddle link below for the sample
https://jsfiddle.net/ismailbaigjsfiddle/3rxyf6ps/1/

**Image of Normal mode working**

[image: Normal mode - working]

**Image of Accordian mode not working**

[image: Accordian mode - Not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the way that directive works, it will move you markup in the "transclude" location. That location is the tab when not in accordion mode. If you inspect the markup in the browser you will see that the ng-click you add is on the dom node that is hidden.

So, if you want to trigger a method when a tab is selected, you should use the "select" handler on the tab. It will be triggered in either mode. Note though that it will also get called on the initial default tab selection.

```
     <tabset>
        <tab heading="tab1" select="myClick()" >Tab 1 content<br />
            <input type="text" />
            <br />

        </tab>
        <tab heading="tab2" select="myClick()">Tab 2 content
            <br />
            <input type="text"/>
            <br />
            <input type="text" />
        </tab>
    </tabset>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/445zvr34/2/

Comment: Thanks mcgraphix,It works on the jsfiddle. i will try including in my project and check. Anyhow the jsfiddle link you shared still contains ng-click. could you change it to select and update the answer. so that others get benefitted.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the link above to the correct fiddle.

Comment: Hey mcgraphix, Its also working in my project as well. Thanks dude. we really had a tough time with this. You made it happens. Cheers.

Comment: We can make use of **IsActive** attribute to make which tab to be active on load.